# Gedmo Doctrine Extensions - Sluggable + Translatable Yaml Configuration

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I'm trying to translate entities with gedmo doctrine extensions.

https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions

I'm using yml as orm mapping file (auto generating entities).

orm.yml:

```
CS\ContentBundle\Entity\Post:
  type:  entity
  table: posts
  repositoryClass: CS\ContentBundle\Entity\PostRepository
  gedmo:
    soft_deleteable:
      field_name: deleted_at
    translation:
      locale: locale
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      length: 11
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    title:
      type: string
      length: 500
      gedmo:
        - translatable
    slug:
      type: string
      length: 500
      gedmo:
        translatable: {}
        slug:
          separator: -
          fields:
            - title
```

I can translate the title without a problem. But slug is not working...

Normally, on default language (tr), slug auto generated without any generation process by me.

Entity file:

```
<?php

namespace CS\ContentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use APY\DataGridBundle\Grid\Mapping as GRID;

/**
 * Post
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deleted_at", timeAware=false)
 * @GRID\Source(columns="id,title,is_active,created_at,updated_at")
 */
class Post implements Translatable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @GRID\Column(title="Başlık", filterable=true)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Locale
     */
    private $locale;

    public function setLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param string $slug
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }
}
```

There is a part in documentation:
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md#using-translationlistener-to-translate-our-slug

I don't know how to apply these listeners.

What should i do to translate the slug automatically?

---

## EDIT

My config.yml for doctrine and stof_doctrine_extensions:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                mapping_types:
                  enum: string
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
        metadata_cache_driver: redis
        query_cache_driver: redis
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
        mappings:
            StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle: ~
            gedmo_translatable:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslatable # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
            gedmo_tree:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTree # this one is optional and will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: "%locale%"
    translation_fallback: true
    orm:
        default:
            tree: true
            sluggable: true
            translatable: true
            timestampable: true
            softdeleteable: true
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and have no idea how to pass EventManager to EntityManager

Comment: These listeners already exist in your app, they are the same that make Translatable and Sluggable working. I think the important information in the doc is "If you want to attach TranslationListener also add it to EventManager after the SluggableListener". Please post your app/config/config.yml file, it will help us to give an answer.

Comment: @R. Canser Yanbakan Did you make it work? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of struggling, I think I've managed to find a solution to your problem. Let's get down to business.

First of all, I've noticed you're using **StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle** which is a wrapper of the **Gedmo Doctrine2 extensions**.

It might have seemed easier to install/use but in the long run it complicates matters. In this case, for example, in order to solve your problem you have to modify listeners and with that bundle the only solution I can come up with is to hack the code and change the priority of the service manually. This leads to the first solution:

**First solution: hack the bundle (not a good one)**

The services can be found in

> StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/Resources/config/listeners.xml

You need to find and modify the sluggable service and increase its priority. That way, this service will execute before the translatable service. The slug would be created first and translatable would store it nicely.

Modification (haven't tried it though I think it might work):

```
<service id="stof_doctrine_extensions.listener.sluggable" class="%stof_doctrine_extensions.listener.sluggable.class%" public="false">
    <tag name="kernel.cache_warmer" priority="1" />
    <call method="setAnnotationReader">
        <argument type="service" id="annotation_reader" />
    </call>
</service>
```

However, I don't like this solution. To be honest, I don't like wrappers. I'm going to give you another solution that I find more satisfactory (and I tried it and works).

**Second solution (and the best one)**

First off, get rid of StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle. Secondly, install Gedmo Doctrine2 extensions (how to do it [here](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md)).

You'll notice that in order to install the extensions you had  to create a file in your bundle containing the necessary services. That is good. Go to that file and modify the priority for the sluggable service:

```
gedmo.listener.sluggable:
        class: Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default, priority: 1 }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
```

And now it is ready.

These are my yml and php for the entity Post (I think they are really similar to yours but can differ):

**YML**

```
DSG\AcmeBundle\Entity\Post:
    type:  entity
    table: posts
    gedmo:
        soft_deleteable:
            field_name: deleted_at
        translation:
            locale: locale
    fields:
        id:
            type: integer
            length: 11
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
        title:
            type: string
            length: 255
            gedmo:
                - translatable
        slug:
            type: string
            length: 255
            unique: true
            gedmo:
                translatable: {}
                slug:
                    separator: _
                    style: camel
                    fields:
                        - title
```

And the **PHP**

```
namespace DSG\AcmeBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;

class Post implements Translatable
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $locale;

    public function setTranslatableLocale($locale)
    {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param string $slug
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }
}
```

When you create and entity and store it in the database, it will create the slug and store the title and the slug in the translation table (if you change the locale).

If you try:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$article = new Post();
$article->setTitle('the title');
$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();

$article = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DSGMDayBundle:Post')->find(1);
$article->setTitle('my title in de');
$article->setTranslatableLocale('de_de'); // change locale
$em->persist($article);
$em->flush();
```

You'll see that your translation table gets two rows, one for the title and the other for the slug for the local de_de.

Hope it helps and kind regards.

Comment: I have tried your solution, second one, without success. I see that translatable is attached to the slug so the Entity mapping is OK, but there is a problem with priorities or sth else. All translatable items are being translated except slug.

Comment: I think you don't even need to override the bundle configuration directly and use Compiler Pass in your bundle extension: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#services-configuration and http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html

Answer (score 1):

Something weird to me : Your ORM config by entity is done in 2 files (yaml and annotation) ?

Listeners look to be well loaded, in the proper order. Maybe it's the entity field config in `orm.yml`. Try to invert translatable and sluggable on the field `slug`:

```
CS\ContentBundle\Entity\Post:
  type:  entity
  table: posts
  repositoryClass: CS\ContentBundle\Entity\PostRepository
  gedmo:
    soft_deleteable:
      field_name: deleted_at
    translation:
      locale: locale
  fields:
    id:
      type: integer
      length: 11
      id: true
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    title:
      type: string
      length: 500
      gedmo:
        - translatable
    slug:
      type: string
      length: 500
      gedmo:
        slug:
          separator: -
          fields:
            - title
        translatable: {}
```

Comment: Just yml for generating entities. Annotations for another bundles that requires annotations for configuration. I will try your answer but i don't think it will work :(

Answer (score 1):

Your configurations is look like correct. However, did you try to update vendors? Maybe some files may be corrupted.

If update process does not work, could you full compare configurations with mine:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
        dql:
            string_functions:
                GroupConcat: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\GroupConcat
                IF: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\IfElse
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
                class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                enabled: true
        mappings:
            StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle: ~
            gedmo_tree:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTree
                is_bundle: false
            translatable:
                type: annotation
                alias: Gedmo
                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                # make sure vendor library location is correct
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
```

And make sure that you do not override the **gedmo.listener.translatable** on your services.yml. If there is any code that overrides the default one, remove it. Default configuration:

```
gedmo.listener.translatable:
        class: Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ @annotation_reader ] ]
            - [ setDefaultLocale, [ %locale% ] ]
            - [ setTranslationFallback, [ false ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle` for sluggable and translatable and had the same problem.

I have searched and tried a while and found a solution working for me:

---

**Entity:**
the slug field gets generated from the name field

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=150, unique=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"}, updatable=true)
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
 */
private $slug;
```

---

**config.yml:** here you have to set `persist_default_translation: true`
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/542#issuecomment-12983553

```
parameters:
    locale: en

doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            gedmo_translatable:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslatable # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false
            gedmo_translator:
                type: annotation
                prefix: Gedmo\Translator\Entity
                dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translator/Entity"
                alias: GedmoTranslator # (optional) it will default to the name set for the mapping
                is_bundle: false

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    translation_fallback: true
    persist_default_translation: true    # I think this does the trick
    orm:
        default:
            sluggable: true
            translatable: true
```

---

**DefaultController** use `ParamConverter` for calling a query which returns correct entity for current locale

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\ParamConverter;

/**
 * @Route("/entry/{slug}", name="entry_detail")
 * @ParamConverter("entry", class="AppBundle:Entry", options={"repository_method" = "findOneByCriteria"})
 */
public function entryDetailAction(Request $request, Entry $entry)
{
    return $this->render('frontend/entry.html.twig', [
        'entry' => $entry,
    ]);
}
```

---

**Entity Repository** with the query method to return entity

```
/**
 * Find an entry by criteria
 * Need this special function, because of translatable
 * https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/issues/232
 *
 * @param $params
 * @return mixed
 */
public function findOneByCriteria(array $params)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($params as $column => $value) {
        if ($i < 1) {
            $query->where("e.$column = :$column");
        } else {
            $query->andWhere("e.$column = :$column");
        }
        $query->setParameter($column, $value);
        $i++;
    }
    $query = $query->getQuery();
    $query->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'Gedmo\\Translatable\\Query\\TreeWalker\\TranslationWalker');
    return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

I hope this example helps someone.